How is XLPy.CallUDF implemented in xlwings
My VBA code uses xlwings to make calls like XLPy.CallUDF "module", "func",Array(a,b,c) to communicate with python functions. I'm curious to understand how such calls are implemented. when I stepped into such calls I see following function was called:
Function XLPy()
    XLPyLoadDLL
    If 0 <> XLPyDLLActivateAuto(XLPy, XLPyCommand, 1) Then Err.Raise 1000, Description:=XLPy
End Function

It is one of the functions generated automatically by xlwings. What confused me is that this function doesn't seem to return anything. By my understanding, under normal circumstances, for XLPy.CallUDF to work, XLPy would typically return an object that has a CallUDF method. So what is the mechanism that the CallUDF (and later call_udf in the xlwings udf.py) is called?

You may be better off to ask the devs on Github
